# Android refresh/update EditText and LinearLayout programmatically does not work

Tags: android, android-layout, android-edittext, android-linearlayout

I need some help with updating an LinearLayout with a lot of EditText boxes that are added programmatically. When new information is added I first remove all the boxes with removeAllViews() to start from clean slate.
I have tab layout as well so by clicking in one of the tabs I run a get/setter(sg class) that I later access from this code when this tab is selected. I can see in the Log printouts that what is supposed to be put into the EditText is right...but in the EditText box in my app the name and values are not updated.
I tried to use invalidate() but it did not work. Any good tip?

Here is a part of the code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab4_layout, container, false);

    ...
    ...
    ...

    //To remove all current views
    myLinearLayout.removeAllViews();
    //myLinearLayout.invalidate();  //<--I tried that   
    for(int i : valueArrayNew){
        if(i==0) {
            editableTextView = new EditText(context);
            editableTextView.setHint(colNames[valueArrayNew.get(i)]);
            editableTextView.setTextSize(20);
            editableTextView.setId(valueArrayNew.get(i));
            editableTextView.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightgrey));
            editableTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
            editableTextView.setText(""+sg.getName());  //<--The name is only updated the first time this code is run.  
            Log.d("HAZE", "Name: " + sg.getName());     //This is not the same name the second time I run and add text to the EditText. This printout is correct and prints the wanted name.
            myLinearLayout.addView(editableTextView);
        }else {
            editableTextView = new EditText(context);
            editableTextView.setHint(colNames[valueArrayNew.get(i)]);
            editableTextView.setTextSize(20);
            editableTextView.setId(valueArrayNew.get(i));
            editableTextView.setHintTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.lightgrey));
            editableTextView.setKeyListener(DigitsKeyListener.getInstance("0123456789.,"));
            editableTextView.setLayoutParams(params);
            editableTextView.setText(""+sg.getValueForNumber(i));   //<--The value is only updated the first time this code is run. 
            myLinearLayout.addView(editableTextView);
        }
    }
    //myLinearLayout.invalidate();  //<--I tried that   

    ...
    ...
    ...

   return rootView;
}




public class MyTabs extends Activity {

// Declaring our tabs and the corresponding fragments.
public ActionBar.Tab Tab1, Tab2, Tab3,Tab4;
Fragment FragmentTab1 = new com.haze.purple.tabs.firstFragmentTab();
Fragment FragmentTab2 = new com.haze.purple.tabs.secondFragmentTab();
Fragment FragmentTab3 = new com.haze.purple.tabs.thirdFragmentTab();
Fragment FragmentTab4 = new com.haze.purple.tabs.fourthFragmentTab();
private static Context context;
ActionBar actionBar;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout._fragment);
    setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

    // Asking for the default ActionBar element that our platform supports.
    actionBar = getActionBar();

    // Screen handling while hiding ActionBar icon.
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);

    // Screen handling while hiding Actionbar title.
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

    // Creating ActionBar tabs.
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    Tab1 = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab1_name);
    Tab2 = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab2_name);
    Tab3 = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab3_name);
    Tab4 = actionBar.newTab().setText(R.string.tab4_name);

    // Setting tab listeners.
    Tab1.setTabListener(new TabListener(FragmentTab1));
    Tab2.setTabListener(new TabListener(FragmentTab2));
    Tab3.setTabListener(new TabListener(FragmentTab3));
    Tab4.setTabListener(new TabListener(FragmentTab4));
    actionBar.addTab(Tab1);
    actionBar.addTab(Tab2);
    actionBar.addTab(Tab3);
    actionBar.addTab(Tab4);
    ...
    ...
```

....and the XML file is like this:

```
A LinearLayout holds it all in in that a ScrollView and in that ScrollView I have another    LinearLayout. IN the last LinearLayout I add all EditText text boxes.

LinearLayout
    ScrollView
        LinearLayout
```

Comment: how are you adding `fragment` to `fragmentManager`

Comment: Hi I'm adding fragments to an actionbar in oncreate in my main activity. I also have a setTabListener in that activity.

Comment: Post ur code of container activity as well, coz what i suspect when u add the fragments to fragmentmanager u're using add. U need to replace the fragment when u click the tab, so the it'll recreate from begining and u can see new data in that.

Comment: I have added more code to my question...please look there. I hope this is what you are looking for:)

Comment: Add your code for `Tab Listener` means the click listener of `Tab` where you're adding `Fragment` to `FragmentManager` or i simply say use `replace` if `FragmentTransation` instead of `add` method

Comment: Hi Thanks for your patience...but I still don't know what you mean...sorry:)

Comment: No issue, Add your code for Tab Listener means the click listener of Tab where you're adding Fragment to FragmentManager

Comment: TabListener implements ActionBar.TabListener.....
    
@Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        ft.replace(R.id.activity_main, fragment);
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your help.
I managed to solve it.
What I did to solve this was to add the code into an AsyncTask(in post execute...because that runs on the main thred I guees) then end with an "myLinearLayout.invalidate() just to be sure".
Now it works:)

Answer (score 0):

You can try to remove the myLinearLayout from its parent view and then create a new LinearLayout programmatically and then add fields dynamically. finally setting the new layout into its parent view

Comment: I really don't know how to do that. I have tried this now as well: rootView.invalidate();
One wierd thing is that I added this code and evertime I switch the button all views are updated correctly but not just for the oncreateView...so I have to push the button:
    Switch onOffSwitch = (Switch)  rootView.findViewById(R.id.on_off_switch);
    onOffSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
     @Override
     public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
     ...
     same code as in oncreateView
     ...
     }
    });